# Change values in df column based on condition using another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe `df1` like below -

```
|email_id | date |role
|abc@gmail.com | '2022-09-08' |1
|abc@gmail.com | '2022-07-01' |1
|abc@gmail.com | nan |1
|xyz@gmail.com | '2022-04-01' |1
|gmh@gmail.com | nan |1
|ytr@gmail.com | '2022-09-08' |1
|ytr@gmail.com | '2022-09-02' |1
```

and `df2` -

```
|email_id | status |role
|abc@gmail.com | 1 |1
|xyz@gmail.com | 0 |2
|gmh@gmail.com | 1 |1
|ytr@gmail.com | 1 |2
```

Update dataframe `df2` column `status` and check if all the records are having date values present,  then status should be updated as `0` else `1`.

Expected output-

```
|email_id | status |role
|abc@gmail.com | 1 |1
|xyz@gmail.com | 0 |2
|gmh@gmail.com | 1 |1
|ytr@gmail.com | 0 |2
```

Explanation of expected output - abc@gmail.com has 2 records date filled third record is nan, so its status should be 1, if there is single record for some email id and it has date filled in then status should be 0 otherwise if single email id has nan date value , status should be 1 and if same email id has multiple records and date all filled in should be 0 as we can see in ytr@gmail.com as there is no nan present.

I tried below lines of code -

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=["email_id","date"])
df1 = (df1[["email_id","date"]]).reset_index()
```

But I am not able to understand how to update df2 based on df1.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One can use a list comprehension as follows

```
df2['status'] = [1 if df1[(df1['email_id'] == email_id) & (df1['date'].isna())].shape[0] > 0 else 0 if df1[(df1['email_id'] == email_id) & (df1['date'].notna())].shape[0] > 0 else 1 for email_id in df2['email_id']]

[Out]:

        email_id  status  role
0  abc@gmail.com       1     1
1  xyz@gmail.com       0     2
2  gmh@gmail.com       1     1
3  ytr@gmail.com       0     2
```